# Limit directory index to authenticated users

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, .htpasswd, directoryindex

Essentially what I am trying to do is to limit directory indexing to authenticated users from a htpasswd file on my Apache server. Here is what I have so far.

```
AuthUserFile C:\XXXXXXXXX\htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Password Protected!"
AuthType Basic
<Limit DirectoryIndex>
require valid-user
</Limit>
```

I have confirmed that this kind of authentication works for normal directory access or for files if I replace "DirectoryIndex" with "GET POST". I tried taking a guess by putting DirectoryIndex in there but it doesn't seem to work. Having googled this issue and looked at a number of other questions here on serverfault, I'm at a loss. If anyone knows how to do this, that would be lovely.

Thanks.

Comment: "limit directory indexing" - Are you referring to the document(s) that the `DirectoryIndex` directive refers to? Or to Apache generated directory-listings (an index of the directory being requested)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DirectoryIndex` (part of mod_dir) sets the file to serve when the client requests a directory. So, to restrict access to this *file*, you need to use a `<Files>` (or `<FilesMatch>`) directive. (You can't reference whatever file(s) the `DirectoryIndex` directive refers to.)

For example, if your `DirectoryIndex` is set to `index.html`, then:

```
<Files "index.html">
    AuthUserFile C:\XXXXXXXXX\htpasswd
    AuthGroupFile /dev/null
    AuthName "Password Protected!"
    AuthType Basic
    Require valid-user
</Files>
```

If you have multiple possible `DirectoryIndex` documents then you can use a `<FilesMatch>` container instead that takes a regex as its argument. For example, if `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html` is set then:

```
<FilesMatch "^index\.(html|php)$">
    # etc.
</FilesMatch>
```

---

Or, by "directory indexing", are you referring to generated directory-listings (mod_autoindex)? But this has little to do with `DirectoryIndex` itself, except that (if enabled) the directory listing is only generated when the `DirectoryIndex` document does not exist.

In this case, to protect the directory-listing only (i.e bare directory) then you can also use a `Files` container, but specify an empty file. For example:

```
# Protect directory-listing only
<Files "">
    # etc.
</Files>
```

---

> ```
> <Limit DirectoryIndex>
> ```

The `Limit` directive restricts the enclosed directives to the stated HTTP *request method(s)* (ie. GET, POST, etc.). `DirectoryIndex` is an Apache directive, not an HTTP request method, so this is invalid.

Comment: Your second solution is what I was trying for. Is there a way to limit it only to actual directory listings and not foo.bar/test/ where there is an index.xxx file?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but "limiting it only to actual directory listings" is what the 3rd code snippet above does.